# Check if a folder exist and rename in vbscript

Tags: vbscript, copy, rename

Okay here is what I want to do. My script copies a folder too the appdata folder on the computer but here is what I need it to do. I need it to check if a folder of that name already exists and if it does to rename it to something else then copy the folder here is my current script that I need to modify to check if the folder excists. Thanx In advance

```
Set oShell = CreateObject("WScript.Shell")
strHomeFolder = oShell.ExpandEnvironmentStrings("%APPDATA%")


Set oShell = CreateObject("WScript.Shell")
Set ofso = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
oShell.CurrentDirectory = oFSO.GetParentFolderName(Wscript.ScriptFullName)

DestinationFolder = strHomeFolder & "\vlc"
SourceFolder = oShell.CurrentDirectory & "\vlc"

dim filesys 
set filesys=CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject") 
If filesys.FolderExists(SourceFolder ) Then 
filesys.CopyFolder SourceFolder , DestinationFolder 
End If
```

Answer (score 4):

You detect whether a destination folder exists the same way you detect whether your source folder exists:

```
If filesys.FolderExists(DestinationFolder) Then
  'do stuff
End If
```

Renaming the folder can be done e.g. like this:

```
filesys.GetFolder(DestinationFolder).Name = "othername"
```

There's no need to change the working directory for what you're doing, BTW, and also for instantiating the Shell and FileSystemObject objects twice.

You should change the way you construct the source and destination paths, though. Fiddling around with path separators is prone to error. It's better to use the `BuildPath` method for constructing paths:

```
DestinationFolder = oFSO.BuildPath(oShell.ExpandEnvironmentStrings("%APPDATA%"), "vlc")
SourceFolder = oFSO.BuildPath(oFSO.GetParentFolderName(WScript.ScriptFullName), "vlc")
```

With that your script could look somewhat like this:

```
Set sh  = CreateObject("WScript.Shell")
Set fso = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")

dst = fso.BuildPath(sh.ExpandEnvironmentStrings("%APPDATA%"), "vlc")
src = fso.BuildPath(fso.GetParentFolderName(WScript.ScriptFullName), "vlc")

If fso.FolderExists(src) Then
  If fso.FolderExists(dst) Then fso.GetFolder(dst).Name = "othername"
  fso.CopyFolder src, dst
End If
```